# Reporting Services displays #Error if no rows to display.

Tags: reporting-services

I'm creating a rather simple report with Reporting Services and noticed that if my data source (which is XML / Web Service) returns no rows, I get #Error text in the text cells that contain some formatting or aggregation logic. It displays one row + the totals row with all datasource cells empty except for the aforementioned calculated ones.

Any idea how I can get rid of these messages?

Answer (score 0):

One thing you can do is set conditional visibility on the details row accessing the "Hidden" property.

```
=IIF(CountRows("DataSetName") = 0,true,false)
```

Another thing you can do is check the fields "IsMissing" property before setting it.

```
=IIF(Fields!Item.IsMissing,"",Fields!Item.Value)
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to do data validation within each of those cells to make sure something is not blank. It is erroring because it is trying to do a calculation on a blank value. Try:

=IIF(IsNothing(Fields!Item.Value),"",Do Calculations)